# Flask admin form edit rules leading to a "does not have field" error

Tags: flask, flask-admin

within my class RequestView(ModelView): I have...

```
form_edit_rules = (
    rules.FieldSet(('name', 'email', 'phone','shopname', 'invoice', 'territory'), 'Customer Information'),
    rules.FieldSet(('address', 'address2', 'city','state','zipcode'), 'Shipping Information'),
    rules.FieldSet(('carrier','num_labels','shipping_label_url', 'shipping_tracking_num', 'shipping_label_url_2', 'shipping_tracking_num_2', 'shipping_label_url_3', 'shipping_tracking_num_3', 'shipping_label_url_4', 'shipping_tracking_num_4'), 'Shipping Labels / Tracking'),
    rules.FieldSet(('created','reason', 'status', 'sales_attention_comments', 'message', 'customer_notes','salesperson'), 'Return Information'),
    rules.FieldSet(('pdffile','credit','audit_reason', 'audit_detail','light_plan','shipping_territory', 'notes','completed'), 'Auditor Fields')
    )
```

For some reason the inclusion of 'phone' is throwing it off and resulting in this error:

ValueError: Form flask_admin.contrib.sqla.form.RequestForm object at 0x11007bc88 does not have field phone

If I remove phone, it works just fine.

I have phone declared in the model as follows:

```
phone = db.Column(PhoneNumberType())
```

Note that I have a custom front-end form that saves data just fine to the phone field. It's only this modification of the admin edit form that is throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Probably due to the complexity of `PhoneNumberType` field flask-admin does not know how to render its widget thus it is missing on the form.

Try adding it as a `StringField` in `form_extra_fields` alongside with `form_edit_rules` like so:

```
from wtforms.fields import StringField

class RequestView(ModelView):
    form_extra_fields = {
        'phone': StringField('phone')
    }
    form_edit_rules = (
        rules.FieldSet(('name', 'email', 'phone','shopname', 'invoice', 'territory'), 'Customer Information'),
        rules.FieldSet(('address', 'address2', 'city','state','zipcode'), 'Shipping Information'),
        rules.FieldSet(('carrier','num_labels','shipping_label_url', 'shipping_tracking_num', 'shipping_label_url_2', 'shipping_tracking_num_2', 'shipping_label_url_3', 'shipping_tracking_num_3', 'shipping_label_url_4', 'shipping_tracking_num_4'), 'Shipping Labels / Tracking'),
        rules.FieldSet(('created','reason', 'status', 'sales_attention_comments', 'message', 'customer_notes','salesperson'), 'Return Information'),
        rules.FieldSet(('pdffile','credit','audit_reason', 'audit_detail','light_plan','shipping_territory', 'notes','completed'), 'Auditor Fields')
    )
```

Validation of phone field is preserved so I guess it will solve your problem.